# Will a `wireless n` network adapter work `wireless g` router?

Tags: wireless-networking, adapter

I have verizon fios internet service.  I believe they use a Wireless G router, but I just have one question.  I currently am using a 54mbps wireless pci adapter in my Windows 7 custom build.  It drops the internet connection all the time and is starting to get very irritating.  I'm thinking about buying a new one, but all the 300mbps cards on newegg are wireless n.

**So my question is**, will a `wireless n` network adapter make a difference with a `wireless g` router?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes an "N" adapter will work with your "G" router - but only at the "G" speed.**

Wireless-N devices can by definition talk to Wireless-G (and B) devices. So if you have a wireless-N adapter in your machine then it will be able to connect to your wireless-G network, but it will only work on the "G" speed so you will not get the "N" advantage.

**If you already have** a wireless-N adapter then you could consider upgrading your router to "N" as well (to get more speeeed). You probably can't find any/many "G" adapters anymore, and you shouldn't worry about it because "N" adapters will work with "G" routers just as well as "G" adapters would.

Answer (score 3):

N might let you pick up a G's signal at a slightly further distance, but to get the most out of an N, you need a N router as well as adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider an external antenna.  Does your PCI Wireless card have an external antenna port?  Look on the back.  It might have a small 2-3 inch antenna right now.

You can buy all sorts of different antennas, optimized to what you need.

For example they have directional antennas, you need to aim at the router which would give you much better reception (if it is possible due to environmental issues like walls, moisture, trees, chicken farms (always blame the chickens!  They never complain!))

You might want to consider the better antenna on the Router end, so that it can push better through those obstacles, if they exist.

RF is fun and tricky!